# Which Transformers have been diagnosed with a mental disorder in canon material or identified as such by a writer/director/etc.?

Tags: transformers

I know those like G1 Red Alert is maniac paranoia, Beast Wars Transmutate is Autistic, and Animated Blitzwing with Split Personality Disorder.

I would like to know others that have mental disorders as well that are canon.

Comment: In the UK comics in the 1980s iirc the Arielbots had a fear of heights.

Comment: Quite a lot of them judging by a quick glance at the wiki.

Comment: I've left this closed just because how you word it leads to an interpretation of what is/isn't a mental disorder. It might be best to word this as "Which Transformers have been diagnosed with a mental disorder in canon material or identified as such by a writer/director/etc.?"

Comment: Yeah - I mean, without a scene where they're at the Transformer Psychiatric Clinic, and Diagnotron tells us their diagnosis, you're back to a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm not asking for opinion based. I'm just asking for actual information. I'm sorry if my own disorders makes this question seem opinion based.

Comment: Understood - asking for either explicitly stated in canon, or established by a creator (what we refer to as "Word of God") makes this clear, as evidenced by the question now being reopened.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed. It's not too broad, because there shouldn't be a huge pile of Transformers with mental disorders. I don't think it was opinion-based to begin with, but adding the point about diagnosis or authorial statements does help.